# OpenVZ machine's venet0 network suddenly down

Tags: linux, networking, openvz

I have setup a further OpenVZ container with the following network setup:

```
venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:192.168.10.168  P-t-P:192.168.10.168  Bcast:192.168.10.168  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

It is running fine for some time, but suddenly deconfigures the interface for no obvious reason.

```
venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

The machine is running imapd, where I find in /var/log/syslog the last lines being as follows:

```
Jul 16 11:59:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2802]: fatal: inet_addr_local[getifaddrs]: getifaddrs: Cannot allocate memory
Jul 16 11:59:40 mail postfix/master[1703]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/cleanup pid 2802 exit status 1
Jul 16 11:59:40 mail postfix/master[1703]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/cleanup: bad command startup -- throttling
Jul 16 12:00:01 mail CRON[2805]: System error
```

There is enough free memory (about 3 Gigabytes).

```
mail:/# uname -a
Linux mail 2.6.32-openvz-042stab081.5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 30 16:40:27 MSK 2013 i686 GNU/Linux

root@hostmachine:~# vzubc 10168
----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 10168     | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|12.4M  90%  88%|13.7M 100%  97%|13.7M|14.1M|    - 
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |2.82M  35%  35%|   8M|   8M|    - 
  privvmpages| 241M   5%   5%| 276M   6%   6%|   4G|   4G|    - 
     shmpages|64.6M  76%  76%|68.4M  81%  81%|  84M|  84M|    - 
      numproc| 101   42%  42%| 126   52%  52%| 240 | 240 |    - 
    physpages| 160M   -    - | 224M   -    - |   - |   - |    - 
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   4G|   4G|    - 
 oomguarpages|  52M   1%   1%|58.9M   1%   1%|   4G|   4G|    - 
   numtcpsock|  43   11%  11%|  61   16%  16%| 360 | 360 |    - 
     numflock|  13    6%   6%|  48   25%  23%| 188 | 206 |    - 
       numpty|   1    6%   6%|  15   93%  93%|  16 |  16 |    - 
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |  48   18%  18%| 256 | 256 |    - 
    tcpsndbuf| 267K  15%  10%|1.65M 100%  63%|1.64M|2.58M|   27 
    tcprcvbuf| 209K  12%   7%| 711K  42%  27%|1.64M|2.58M|    - 
 othersockbuf| 495K  45%  24%| 743K  67%  36%|1.07M|   2M|    - 
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |8.52K   3%   3%| 256K| 256K|    - 
 numothersock| 360  100% 100%| 360  100% 100%| 360 | 360 | 2.35K
   dcachesize|3.42M 105%  98%|3.46M 106% 100%|3.25M|3.46M|    - 
      numfile|1.52K  16%  16%|1.77K  19%  19%|9.09K|9.09K|    - 
    numiptent|  20   15%  15%|  20   15%  15%| 128 | 128 |    - 
    swappages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   - |   - |    - 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The host is Debian 7.2, the guest is Debian 8.1.

Is there some misconfiguration which I am not aware of? Can someone please help me?!

Comment: As I said in my answer you should definitely increase `numothersock`'s barrier & limit, say, to doubled value (720).  Then restart the container to see how it improves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot guess the cause of the network down, but it looks like your container ran out of resources allocated, which could indirectly cause the problem.   You can run `vzubc` on the HN to see circumstances like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 1078      | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
  lockedpages|   -    -    - |12.3M   1%   1%|   1G|   1G|    - 
    physpages| 144M   -   14%| 274M   -   26%|   - |   1G|    - 
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |   2G|   - |    - 
 oomguarpages| 131M  12%   - | 132M  13%   - |   1G|   - |    - 
    swappages|39.6M   -    3%|44.3M   -    4%|   - |   1G|    - 

----------------------------------------------------------------
CT 1072      | HELD Bar% Lim%| MAXH Bar% Lim%| BAR | LIM | FAIL
-------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-----+------
     kmemsize|5.51M   4%   4%|6.37M   5%   5%| 128M| 128M|    - 
  lockedpages|   -    -    - | 580K  56%  56%|   1M|   1M|    2 
  privvmpages| 582M  14%  14%| 625M  15%  15%|   4G|   4G|    4 
     shmpages| 256K 0.3% 0.3%| 260K 0.3% 0.3%|  84M|  84M|    - 
      numproc|  68   28%  28%|  84   35%  35%| 240 | 240 |    - 
    physpages|43.7M   -    - |60.1M   -    - |   - |   - |    - 
  vmguarpages|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 132M|   - |    - 
 oomguarpages|4.88M   4%   - |5.94M   5%   - | 102M|   - |    - 
   numtcpsock|   3  0.8% 0.8%|   4    1%   1%| 360 | 360 |    - 
     numflock|   1  0.5% 0.5%|   3    2%   2%| 188 | 206 |    - 
       numpty|   -    -    - |   -    -    - |  16 |  16 |    - 
   numsiginfo|   -    -    - |   9    3%   3%| 256 | 256 |    - 
    tcpsndbuf|51.1K   3%   2%|68.1K   4%   2%|1.64M|2.58M|    - 
    tcprcvbuf|  48K   2%   2%|  64K   3%   2%|1.64M|2.58M|    - 
 othersockbuf|4.52K 0.4% 0.2%|12.8K   1% 0.6%|1.07M|   2M|    - 
  dgramrcvbuf|   -    -    - |   -    -    - | 256K| 256K|    - 
 numothersock|   5  0.7% 0.7%|   8    1%   1%| 720 | 720 |    - 
   dcachesize|3.45M 106%  99%|3.46M 106% 100%|3.25M|3.46M|    - 
      numfile| 153    2%   2%| 260    2%   2%|9.09K|9.09K|    - 
    numiptent|  20   15%  15%|  20   15%  15%| 128 | 128 |    -
```

See [/proc/user_beancounters](https://openvz.org/Proc/user_beancounters) and [UBC parameters table](https://openvz.org/UBC_parameters_table) for meanings of the parameters shown above.
Note that there could be 2 types of output according to whether [VSWAP](https://openvz.org/VSwap) is enabled (CT 1078) or not (CT 1072).

What you sholud pay attention to in each table are FAIL counters.  It means how many times the container failed to allocate that resource in the past, by attempting to request more than its barrier (BAR) or limit (LIM) value.  So if FAIL is more than 0 and still keeps increasing, you need to allocate more for that resouce.

You can increase/decrease BAR or LIM by `vzctl` at any time.  For containers with VSWAP, you can increase `physpages` (memory) or `swappages` (virtual swap) by `--ram` or `--swap` respectively.

```
vzctl set 1078 --save --ram 2G --swap 2G
```

For containers without VSWAP you would often increase `privvmpages` for memory, and occasionally need to adjust other resources too.

```
vzctl set 1072 --save --privvmpages 5G
```

FAIL counters are reset to 0 on boot of the container they belong to.   `vzubc -r` shows relative values for FAIL counters since the previous run.